# ElementNotVisibleException: Python + Selenium, login credentials on web

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm close to losing my mind if someone can help keep my sanity. I cannot get past this "ElementNotVisibleException:" error. I've tried multiple techniques I've read through the web and nothing works. This one seems pretty straightforward with a `.send_keys` used with a `WebDriverWait` until the presence of ID is located. What am I missing?

When I step through it line by line it works.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chromedriver = "/Users/username/.conda/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("url")
delay = 3
username = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login_username'))).send_keys("username")
password = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login_password'))).send_keys("password")
```

Comment: Try adding more time to the delay, set it to 15 and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `visibility_of_element_located`expected condition for your case.

Hope it helps you!